# Looking for alternative analog/digital circuits to drive low impedance with high current

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, bjt, load, high-current

I am looking to drive a load with the specifications as follows:

- Load Resistance = 2.2 ±0.3 Ω
- Load Current = 1.5-4.5 A
- Nominal Load Current = 2 A
- The load current should never go below 1.25 A at any given condition.

My initial try to achieve this, is to use an LDO with V<sub>in</sub> = 5 V or higher and setting its V<sub>out</sub> = 2.2 Ω × 2 A = 4.4 V.

This is as shown in the image below:
[image]

However, I feel this is not an ideal way of approaching this requirement. Other methods that I can possibly think of, is to use paralleling of BJTs or MOSFETs and connect to load at the collector/drain.

I am looking for circuits to meet this requirement and how this is done in industry.

Comment: what kind of frequencies ?

Comment: Do you plan to adjust the voltage on the 2.2 ohm load to get 1.5 to 4.5 amps? If it is fixed at 4.4 V, it will always be 2.0 A +/- 15%.

Comment: "at any condition" -- what conditions would you be concerned about? Can the load resistance vary?  Supply voltage?

Comment: If you already have a stable 5V and don't need an exact 2A at around 2.2Ω, you could just use a Schottky diode to drop the voltage to about 4.5V. Or just use a switching buck converter with synchronous rectification. There are a few modules available on the market for cheap, and you can adjust both the voltage and the current efficiently, and they will be stable too.

Comment: @PStechPaul, no we are not trying to vary load to get 1.5-4.5A. The load is fixed at 2.2ohms. And the variation of current we are talking about here, is due to the variations in supply/input voltage.

Comment: Why do you think your proposed solution is not ideal?  What you've drawn is a typical power delivery system.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that the voltage source you have available is *at least* 5V, implying that it is perfectly capable of providing 2A without falling below that value.

The requirement that the load have *at least* 1.25A through it is fundamentally at odds with this above condition, since if the source is *at least* 5V, then you are able (with the right setup) to provide at least \$\frac{5V}{2.2\Omega-0.3\Omega} = 2.6A\$ under all conditions.

The actual voltage across the load, to sustain 2A through it, will be at a maximum with a load of greatest resistance, \$R_{LOAD(MAX)} = 2.2\Omega + 0.3\Omega = 2.5\Omega\$. The corresponding voltage will be:

$$ V_{LOAD} = I_{LOAD} \times R_{LOAD(MAX)} = 2A \times 2.5\Omega = 5V $$

Suddenly I see your problem. You cannot guarantee 2A through a 2.5Ω load using any voltage regulator with significant drop-out voltage. The question is, can a regulator maintain 1.25A through the load, even during drop-out?

The minimum voltage across the load to maintain 1.25A through it is:

$$ V = 1.25A \times 2.5\Omega = 3.13V $$

If your supply is guaranteed to be at least 5V, then you require a regulator with drop-out voltage at most:

$$ V_{DROPOUT} = 5V - 3.13V = 1.9V $$

There are plenty of commercial devices out there that easily beat this specification, but it I understand it would be better just to guarantee 2A at all times. Besides, a system design to deliberately operate a regulator *in dropout* is not ideal; I'm not sure that specifications for such operation are even available for regulators. It might be true, for some given regulator, that drop-out voltage is guaranteed to be remain constant as input falls below \$V_{OUT}+V_{DROPOUT}\$, but I won't make such a claim here.

Nominally, the voltage you need across the load is:

$$V = I\times R = 2A \times 2.2\Omega = 4.4V $$

Perhaps it's better to find a way to get exactly 4.4V across the load at all times. This is effectively asking for a regulated 4.4V output, even when the input source itself falls to 5V. That's a dropout of 0.6V. Regulators with such low dropout are available, but it might be difficult to find one that can promise that with a load current close to 2A.

You *can* find boost/buck regulators, though; DC-DC converters able to produce +5V given any input from, say, +3V and up. I will leave you to research that option.

The other way is to roll your own linear regulator, which is not difficult for resistive loads. The only reason a typical 3 or 4-terminal regulator has a "dropout voltage" in the first place is that the internal error amplifier must operate from whatever input potential is provided, and it is therefore unable to apply any potential greater than that to the base/gate of its own pass transistor.

If you are able to implement an error amplifier which operates from a supply with significantly greater potential than the required regulated output, then this problem goes away.

You can use any cheap, low power DC-DC converter to produce, say 12V (from whatever voltage your "5V or more" supply is producing) to operate the error amplifier, reference etc. You will be able to obtain a gate/base signal for the pass transistor(s) well beyond what a 3/4-terminal device could:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLnZdD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This uses a closed loop to maintain a fixed voltage of 4.4V (produced by the TL431 reference IC) across the load, and therefore a fixed current through it of 2A, even as the input voltage (S) drops slightly below 5V. Here I sweep the input voltage from 0V to 12V, and plot voltage across, and current through the load:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, voltage remains exactly 4.4V for all inputs above 4.4V, only falling below that when the input supply drops below 4.4V. We essentially have a zero-volt dropout voltage regulator.

You never told us what the *maximum* source voltage will be. This is important, because it will determine the maximum power dissipation in M1. Here's how power in M1 varies with input voltage:

[image]

At 1W dissipation you should start thinking about heat-sinking. At 2W the heat-sink will have to be substantial. Higher than 4W is squarely in the realm of forced-air cooling (a fan).

You can mitigate heating by sharing the load across multiple pass transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF2BUc.png)</sup>

Resistors R2, R3 and R4 are necessary to balance current through each transistor. Without them, any mismatch in transistor parameters will cause one of them to dominate, and do all the heavy lifting, getting hot while the  others sit back and relax.